Having issue with javascript tabs not working properly
I'm a new user and a new coder just trying to make a portfolio site. I wanted my site to have tabs that would swap between content, but I cannot get the javascript to work at all.
I just ran with a template from w3schools and replaced it with the names of the classes/ids in my code. I was expecting for a normal usual tab function. What happens here is that all the content from the two tabs show up, and when you click any of the tabs it disappears until you refresh the page.
I apologize that the code isn't minimal, I don't actually know how much I can trim without losing context. If it matters, I ran this code on firefox


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto" src: url("Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff") format("woff");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto" src: url("Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

.sidebar-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
}

.sidebar img {
  height: 200px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 50px 0 0 400px;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

.page-tab {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tab {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.sidebar-button,
.tab {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #D99023;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar-button:hover,
.tab:hover {
  background-color: #9C5400;
}

.sidebar-button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.page-tab button:active {
  background-color: #9C5400;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.gallery-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.gallery-container img {
  height: 350px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Frogcroaks</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <nav class="sidebar">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
      <button class="sidebar-button">
          <a href="home.html">Home</a>
        </button>

      <button class="sidebar-button">
          <a href="commissions.html">Commission</a>
        </button>

      <button class="sidebar-button">
          <a href="about.html">About & Contact</a>
        </button>
    </nav>

    <div class="content">
      <nav class="page-tab">
        <button class="tab" onclick="openGallery(event, 'character-design')">
            Character Design
          </button>

        <button class="tab" onclick="openGallery(event, 'illustration')">
            Illustration
          </button>

      </nav>

      <div id="character-design" class="gallery-container gallery">
        <img src="images/poufdesign1.png" alt="" class="gallery">
        <img src="images/poufdesign2.png" alt="" class="gallery">
        <img src="images/poufdesign3.png" alt="" class="gallery">
        <img src="images/fairy-ring.png" alt="" class="gallery">
        <img src="images/luminae.png" alt="" class="gallery">
        <img src="images/griffoy.png" alt="" class="gallery">
        <img src="images/pokemon.png" alt="" class="gallery">
      </div>

      <div id="illustration" class="gallery-container gallery" style="display=" none "">
        <img src="images/eloa-growth2.png" alt="" class="gallery">
        <img src="images/eloa-growth1.png" alt="" class="gallery">
        <img src="images/seviper-zangoose.png" alt="" class="gallery">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <script>
    function openGallery(evt, galleryName) {
      // Declare all variables
      var i, gallery, tab;

      gallery = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery");
      for (i = 0; i < gallery.length; i++) {
        gallery[i].style.display = "none";
      }

      tab = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
      for (i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        tab[i].className = tab[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }

      document.getElementById(galleryName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>




as soon as you click one of the "tabs" buttons, you display:none ALL the img tags - hence no content

@JaromandaX that part was copied straight from the example template, so I'm not sure how i'd change it

the w3schools example template is wrong then (hands up if you're surprised w3schools is wrong) or you've changed something ... for example, I doubt any even mildly useful site would suggest style="display=" none "" since that's pure garbage

tabs with no javascript required

There are many things wrong with the code you've provided. Here's a working solution. I've written JavaScript into a separate file (script.js) and linked it to HTML using the  tag with the src attribute. If you prefer to write it in the HTML document as you have in your code, replace the content of your HTML's <script> tag with the JS code written below.


"use strict";

const tabBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-btn");
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery");

tabBtns.forEach(function (btn, i) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (tabs[i].classList.contains("hidden")) {
      tabs[i].classList.toggle("hidden");
      tabs[Math.abs(i - 1)].classList.toggle("hidden");
    }
  });
});
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  src: url("Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff") format("woff");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  src: url("Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

.sidebar-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px;
}

.sidebar img {
  height: 200px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 50px 0 0 400px;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

.page-tab {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tab-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.sidebar-button,
.tab-btn {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #d99023;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar-button:hover,
.tab-btn:hover {
  background-color: #9c5400;
}

.sidebar-button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.page-tab button:active {
  background-color: #9c5400;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.gallery img {
  height: 350px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">
        <nav class="sidebar">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
            <button class="sidebar-button">
                <a href="home.html">Home</a>
            </button>

            <button class="sidebar-button">
                <a href="commissions.html">Commission</a>
            </button>

            <button class="sidebar-button">
                <a href="about.html">About & Contact</a>
            </button>
        </nav>

        <div class="content">
            <nav class="page-tab">
                <button class="tab-btn" id="btn-character-design">
                    Character Design
                </button>

                <button class="tab-btn" id="btn-illustration">
                    Illustration
                </button>

            </nav>

            <div id="tab-character-design" class="gallery">
                <img src="images/poufdesign1.png" alt="" class="gallery-img">
                <img src="images/poufdesign2.png" alt="" class="gallery-img">
                <img src="images/poufdesign3.png" alt="" class="gallery-img">
                <img src="images/fairy-ring.png" alt="" class="gallery-img">
                <img src="images/luminae.png" alt="" class="gallery-img">
                <img src="images/griffoy.png" alt="" class="gallery-img">
                <img src="images/pokemon.png" alt="" class="gallery-img">
            </div>

            <div id="tab-illustration" class="gallery hidden">
                <img src="images/eloa-growth2.png" alt="" class="gallery-img">
                <img src="images/eloa-growth1.png" alt="" class="gallery-img">
                <img src="images/seviper-zangoose.png" alt="" class="gallery-img">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>




I have also made minor modifications to the HTML and CSS code (classes and IDs). So, you might want to replace your HTML and CSS code with the solution's HTML and CSS.
